# MVC's AllowAnonymousAttribute not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reference, http-authentication

The AuthorizeAttribute shows up just fine, but for the life of me I can't figure out where the AllowAnonymousAttribute class is.

Whenever I add it to code, I get compiler errors.

```
[Authorize] //works fine
public ActionResult DoSomething(){ 
  ...
}

[AllowAnonymous] //COMPILER ERROR type not found. Red squigglies. Bad.
public ActionResult Foo() {
  ...
}
```

I'm in an MVC3 project.

Comment: AllowAnonymous - it's a custom attribute?...

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy no, it is an MVC4 attribute.

Comment: @Husein I was surprised cause the tag for topic is asp.net-mvc-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3, or more precisely the System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0 assembly does not contain AllowAnonymousAttribute.

It was added in ASP.NET MVC 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute_methods%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

There's an AllowAnonymousAttribute in System.Web.Http assembly as well, but I could not get it working with my ASP.NET MVC 3 project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default all actions provide access to anonymous users.

Here is the good example for security implementation with Anonymous attribute:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Or this (example of custom [Authorize] attribute):
http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Yes, of course.  What I needed to do was more of a situation where all actions would require authentication, and just a few actions would allow anonymous access.

Comment: The first example represent exactly that you need :)