# what attribute can open a controller's action to require no authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc controller

The page is blocked under FormsAuthentication

How can I make one specific action to require no FormsAuthentication?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MVC 4 you can use [`[AllowAnonymousAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.108).aspx).

If running an earlier version there are other alternatives, for example discusssed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363573/358970